# What's the latest on MySQL Proxy?

Tags: mysql, mysql-proxy

Does somebody here know the latest state of the development of MySQL Proxy?
Most materials I found on web are outdated.

Answer (score 6):

From an [email on the MySQL lists](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/227139) sent earlier this month, Shawn Green (a MySQL Principal Technical Support Engineer) reports:

> Thanks to the corporate changes of the last few years, the sole developer has been too busy doing his primary job to really put any more time into the project and no person or group from the community has stepped forward to help push the project to a final deliverable state.

So I suppose the latest state of development is it's on hold.

Comment: I would add that one thing: I wish mysql-proxy was written in pure C/C++ (open source, of course) and not involve any LUA.

Answer (score 3):

The new MySQL Router is replacing MySQL Proxy. Please take a look and let us know what you think!

I'd love to hear what features you most want in future versions.

http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-router-on-labs-the-newest-member-of-the-mysql-family/

http://mysqlhighavailability.com/easy-load-balancing-and-high-availability-using-mysql-router/